# Need to call a function from one file to another file in react without importing whole component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two files First.js and Second.js they are not child and Parent they have a lot of functions inside them. I want to use 1 function which is inside First.js into another file Second.js.

First.js

```
export default Header extends React.Component{

  constructor(){
    super();
  }

  updateXS(e){
    alert('Test');
  }
}
```

Second.js

```
export default Second extends React.Component{

  constructor(){
    super();

  }
  solveVariable() {
    updateXS()// from first file
  }


  render(){
    return (
      <div className="displayinline col-md-12 ">
         <button onClick={self.solveVariable.bind(this)}>Solve</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

On click of Solve button in need to call updateXS() there are other functions render() also present in the first file.

Comment: If the function  is reusable then it should not be part of component. Instead you can create a utility function and import in both the components.

Comment: that function is using props and other methods and properties from its own.

Comment: pass data you are using through arguments.

Comment: Use [React Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) and you will be fine I guess. @wizkhalifa

Comment: any example? @SumanKundu

Comment: You need to understand it so read this [blog](https://hackernoon.com/refs-in-react-all-you-need-to-know-fb9c9e2aeb81)

Answer (score 0):

You need to bubble up the action to a container

```
export default Second extends React.Component{

  constructor(){
    super();

  }
  solveVariable() {
    this.props.handleSolveVariable();
  }


  render(){
    return (
      <div className="displayinline col-md-12 ">
         <button onClick={self.solveVariable.bind(this)}>Solve</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Then the container can handle the solving part, set a state and pass it to the children.

```
class Container extends Component {
  solveThis(e) {
    // ... calculate
    return result;
  }
  handleSolveVariable = (e) => {
    const result = this.solveThis(e);
    this.setState({result})
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <First result={this.state.result}/>
        <Second result={this.state.result} handleSolveVariable={this.handleSolveVariable}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

You should keep in mind the «actions up, data down» philosophy of react and not rely on observing events like in Jquery.

The children can react based on the new state an rerender.
You can also use componentWillReceiveProps to compare new props and react to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can bubble up or create an utils function file and then export them. If you think is a function that you might use across your application it might be the best solution.